# Leading / Trailing swipe actions completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Lets say I have a simple action:

```
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "View Details", handler: { (action, view, completionHandler) in
     viewModel.doSomething(with:...)

     completionHandler(true)
 })
```

So there is a [handler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextualaction/2902341-handler) but it accepts only a `Bool`. As per docs:

> The handler block to call in response to the selection of an action

But I am trying to perform something, after the "actions menu" is completely dismissed (after "automatic swipe back animation is done), rather than at the moment when I select (to be more precise, make a tap on) specific action button.

Am I missing something, or I would need a workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: I mean I know I can use something like `didEndEditingRow(at:..)` but that would kinda add additional logic about which action is executed...

Comment: FYI - The completionHandler is there for you to tell the cell when the action has been completed and the `Bool` parameter is to indicate whether is was successful or not.

Comment: So are you looking to perform something else in addition to the selected action or are you trying to delay the selected action until the actions menu is fully dismissed?

Comment: I am trying to delay certain code execution, after the actions menu is fully dismissed. @HangarRash Ofc without using GCD :-)

Comment: I need to do the same thing - perform an action once the swipe animation is complete. Basically to reset selection because the editing mode unsets it. On a table view, the method you mentioned above is the correct way to do this. However, when using a UICollectionView in List mode, I believe this method is not available. Have you found anything you can share?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the code in `Task { @MainActor in // your code here }`  execution is delayed until the next pass of the run loop.